# How to select specific rows by subsetting the accompanying geometry column with a certain range of coordinates in R

Tags: r, r-sf

Recently, I am trying to make a river map for a certain region. To this end, I obtained the river data from HydroRivers and I would like to subset this data with a certain range of coordinates so that I would have the initial needed map. Therefore, I wrote the following code to read the data into R and tried to subset it with a certain range of coordinates

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

river_data <- read_sf("~/HydroRIVERS_v10_eu.shp")
x_range <- c(25.7, 45.3)
y_range <- c(35.7, 42.3)

my_selection <- river_data$geometry[st_intersects(river_data$geometry, st_bbox(c(x_range, y_range))),]
```

Yet, this code did not work out well by throwing out an error. Therefore, I would like to know how I can subset a geometry object with a certain range of coordinates so that I would have only rows for a certain region.

PS. Here are the specifics for the data so that you may understand my problem better.

Column names are

```
[1] "HYRIV_ID"   "NEXT_DOWN"  "MAIN_RIV"   "LENGTH_KM"  "DIST_DN_KM" "DIST_UP_KM"
[7] "CATCH_SKM"  "UPLAND_SKM" "ENDORHEIC"  "DIS_AV_CMS" "ORD_STRA"   "ORD_CLAS"  
[13] "ORD_FLOW"   "HYBAS_L12"  "geometry"
```

And the geometry column that I would like to subset has the following rows:

```
Geometry set for 6 features 
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 56.49375 ymin: 81.33125 xmax: 59.30625 ymax: 81.78958
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
First 5 geometries:
LINESTRING (59.2625 81.78958, 59.30625 81.78958)
LINESTRING (58.24167 81.77708, 58.13542 81.7770...
LINESTRING (57.50833 81.51042, 57.44375 81.5104...
LINESTRING (57.07917 81.50417, 57.06875 81.5145...
LINESTRING (56.55208 81.33125, 56.54792 81.3354...
```

Comment: What was the actual error? List returned from `st_intersects()` is not suitable for submitting in that manner, you probably want lengths of the list instead, but with this kind of use of bbox it might have thrown out error even before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be 3 potential errors:

- comma in `river_data$geometry[something, ]`
- subsetting directly with `st_intersects()`result
- `st_bbox()` as `st_intersects()` parameter

I assume it was the last one that triggered the error.
For selecting features by intersection and using `nc` example icluded in sf package, one might want to try something like this:

```r
library(sf)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
bb_surry <- st_as_sfc(st_bbox(nc[nc$NAME == "Surry",]))
isects <- st_intersects(nc, bb_surry)

# intersects result, sparse geometry binary predicate list (sgbp)
isects
#> Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 100, where the
#> predicate was `intersects'
#> first 10 elements:
#>  1: (empty)
#>  2: 1
#>  3: 1
#>  4: (empty)
#>  5: (empty)
#>  6: (empty)
#>  7: (empty)
#>  8: (empty)
#>  9: (empty)
#>  10: 1

# more useful forms for subsetting: 
lengths(isects)
#>   [1] 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>  [38] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>  [75] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
nc_sub1 <- nc[lengths(isects) > 0,]

t(isects)
#> Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 1, where the predicate
#> was `intersects'
#>  1: 2, 3, 10, 18, 23, 25
nc_sub2 <- nc[unlist(t(isects)),]

# are results same?
identical(nc_sub1, nc_sub2)
#> [1] TRUE

plot(nc$geometry[unlist(t(st_intersects(nc, nc_sub1)))], lwd = .1)
plot(nc_sub1$geometry, col = "gold", lwd = .2, add = TRUE )
plot(bb_surry, border = "red", lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>